# Is There Any Database for Catholics to Determine if particular Corporations and Organizations are Good Moral Choices for Donation or Investment?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, tithe, conscience

Lots of corporations and non-profit organizations do good work, and Catholics may want to invest in them or donate to them. But, although lots of good work might be done by a corporation or non-profit, they might also participate in grave evils, through the funding of abortion, slave labor, teaching falsehoods on sexual ethics or providing contraception, etc. Catholics who want to donate or invest in these groups might want to verify beforehand that their money will not be used to cooperate with these evils, *especially formally*, as a matter of conscience. It would be helpful to us if someone knows of a Catholic database designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some who keep track of organizations it would be immoral for Catholics to support:

- [Life Decisions International](https://fightpp.org) publishes a [*List of Boycott Targets*](https://fightpp.org/publications/the-caleb-report-67zsw) and [*The Boycott Handbook*](https://fightpp.org/publications/the-boycott-handbook-87npb) of corporations who donate to the world's largest abortion provider Planned Parenthood.
- [Children of God for Life](https://cogforlife.org/) keeps track of [vaccines that use cells from aborted human fetuses](https://cogforlife.org/wp-content/uploads/Abortion-Tainted-Vaccines.pdf).
- The [Lepanto Institute](https://lepantoin.org/) publishes [Charity Reports](https://lepantoin.org/charity-reports/) of those charities who support (or not) abortion, contraception, homosexuality, Marxism, heresy.

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed that LDI requires payment to access their boycott targets list. I could understand for other products like the handbook, but if they really care about boycotting abortion-funding corporations, one would think they would make the list freely available. The Lepanto Institute is the closest to what I'm looking for, but they only cover charities. Still good to know about that one.